How to route only qBittorrent traffic through a SoftEther VPN
I am looking to connect to a SoftEther VPN server and only route the traffic from qBittorrent through the VPN. I am using the VPN Client and vpncmd programs, all running on Debian. I have managed to connect to the VPN and even route traffic through the VPN, but it routed all traffic.
Here is what I tried:
After connecting to the VPN,
ip route add (VPN server IP address)/32 via (previous gateway address) - add a route through the VPN
(I got the VPN server IP address using the nslookup command.)
ip route del default - remove the old route
dhclient vpn_vpn - request an IP address
That did work, but it routed all trafic through the VPN, I tried without the ip route del default command and binding using the "Network interface" option in qBittorrent to bind to the vpn_vpn interface, but qBittorrent had no connection.
If there is any extra information that's needed, do let me know.


binding using the "Network interface" option in qBittorrent to bind to the vpn_vpn interface, but qBittorrent had no connection.

This mechanism still relies on having routes. Without a default route, your computer doesn't know which gateway to send the packets through – Ethernet is a multi-point connection (really a whole network), so each packet needs to be addressed to a specific MAC address (e.g. your gateway's MAC), it cannot be simply blasted to the entire network.
Instead, you need more routes:

You probably have two default routes, one through Ethernet and another through the VPN. Instead of doing the exchange as you described, keep the Ethernet default route in the main routing table, but add the VPN default route to a separate routing table.
Unfortunately the Linux dhclient (or its dhclient-script rather) cannot do that automatically, but you could either edit dhclient-script to add the table XXX option or delete/re-add the default route manually:
ip -4 route add default via <gw> dev vpn_vpn table 1234

systemd-networkd's DHCP client can do that automatically using [DHCPv4] Table=.

Now that you have two routing tables with different default routes, add a policy routing (PBR) rule so that any packets sent from your VPN IP address choose the table that has the VPN routes:
ip -4 rule add from <vpn_ip> lookup 1234

It would also be best to have the DHCP client do this, but alternatively you can specify a whole subnet as from (i.e. not necessarily your exact address).



Thanks for the quick reply, I've been trying to get the commands that you sent to work for the past few days, for some reason I was getting the 'Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.' error, I tried it on Ubuntu and on Mint, and had the same error. Anyway, today it worked on Ubuntu, but not on Mint. The commands completed without error, but the situation is the same in qBittorrent, no network connection when you set it to bind to the VPN interface. Could it be that I used the VPN IP from nslookup, where should I get the IP?

nslookup? vpn_ip is supposed to be your address, so you should be getting it from ip addr.

Ahhh, I see. I tried it again with the address from the 'ip addr' command, and the result remains the same, commands complete without error, but qBittorrent (while being bound to the VPN interface) has no connection. The rest of the OS still has a connection through the standard ethernet interface.
